# (this.internalValue || []).findIndex is not a function when enabling multiple selection on v-select

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using Vue.js with Vuetify.

Following is my minimal reproducible example:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-select v-model="site" :items="sites" item-value="_id" item-text="name"></v-select>
    <v-btn @click="showSelections">Show Selections</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',

  data: () => ({
    site: [],
    sites: [
  {
    name: 'Vancouver',
    _id: '5d9c276784e00100699281e2',
  },
  {
    name: 'LA',
    _id: '5d9c276784e00100699281e5',
  },
  {
    name: 'Montreal',
    _id: '5d9c276784e00100699281e3',
  },
],
  }),
  methods: {
    showSelections: function() {
      console.log(this.site);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This example works perfect until you want to enable multiple selection on the `v-select` component.

```
<v-select v-model="site" :items="sites" multiple item-value="_id" item-text="name"></v-select>
```

As soon as you click the combobox, you'd get this:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: (this.internalValue || []).findIndex is not a function"

found in

---> <VSelectList>
       <VThemeProvider>
         <VMenu>
           <VSelect>
             <VMain>
               <VApp>
                 <App> at src/App.vue
                   <Root>

TypeError: (this.internalValue || []).findIndex is not a function
    at VueComponent.findExistingIndex (VSelect.ts?1576:338)
    at VueComponent.selectItem (VSelect.ts?1576:816)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3888)
    at click (VSelectList.ts?7bd1:169)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
```

Comment: Seems to work in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWbodxb?editors=1010).

Comment: Yes, it is working there. Can you please bootstrap a new Vue application and try offline?

Comment: With this: https://gitlab.com/sntshk/temp-vuetify?

Comment: Yes, I used `vue create proj` with defaults, and then `vue add vuetify` with defaults. That effectively creates the same project you linked to.

Comment: Still have the same issue when I conditionally change the `multiple` property of v-select.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue caused by Vue CLI `4.5.11` transpiling Vuetify. If you remove `vuetify` from `transpileDependencies`, your example works properly:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // transpileDependencies: [
  //   'vuetify'
  // ]
}
```

Interestingly, this isn't a problem at all (no config changes needed) with Vue CLI `5.0.0-alpha.4`, so consider upgrading.

Comment: I tried commenting these lines. Now the error is: `TypeError: (this.internalValue || []).slice is not a function`.

Comment: For creating this example, my version was "~4.5.0".

Comment: It is `@vue/cli 4.5.10`.

Comment: I don't see the error in Vue CLI 5. I recommend upgrading.

Comment: Anyhow the production application (not this example) does not uses Vue CLI. The project is build using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I leave you here as I have it in case it works for you:

```html
<!-- VueJS Template -->
<v-select :items="arrayItems" v-model="arrayItemsSelected" label="Items" item-text="text" outlined multiple chips attach dark></v-select>
```

```js
// VueJS Data
export default {
  data: () => ({
    arrayItemsSelected: [],
    arrayItems: [
      { value: "Item1", text: "Item1" },
      { value: "Item2", text: "Item2" },
      { value: "Item3", text: "Item3" },
      { value: "Item4", text: "Item4" },
      { value: "Item5", text: "Item5" },
    ],
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was toggling the `multiple` property of the v-select. See the reproduction link: https://codepen.io/kkojot/pen/MWOpYqZ

To avoid this error you have to clear the property bound to v-model and change it empty object `{}` or empty array `[]` accordingly.

```
computed: {
 isMultiple() {
  //comment the if statment below to see the 'TypeError: (this.internalValue || []).findIndex is not a function'
  if (this.multiple) this.site = [];
  else this.site = {};
  return this.multiple;
},
```

},